# textArea won't display what it's reading from file?

Tags: java

I can't figure out why my textArea won't display what it's reading from a text file. The filename shows the correct location so I'm assuming this is where the issue is:

```
try {
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(filename);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
    textArea.read(br, null);
    br.close();
    textArea.requestFocus();
} catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Error opening");
}
```

Comment: how is [tag:eclipse] related to your code?

Comment: are you getting any error? Which one?

Comment: If you are not getting any IOException then you probably don't add the text area to the GUI or the file is empty. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) if you need more help.

Comment: I'm using eclipse to write this code, and no I'm not getting any errors. I output the filename to the console to make sure it's the correct file path, and it is so the issue is not related to finding the file path.

Comment: **Handle exception in a good way.** use `e.printStackTract()` to figure out the issue.

Comment: @JanDvorak how the exception will be generated because it's eaten in catch block.